# 403 Forbidden when using basic auth and ajax call to a REST API

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, tomcat, cors

I'm trying to write a JS script to make calls to Atlassian Stash via its supported REST API.  The script resides on port 80.  The server is on port 7990.  I was originally getting cross-domain scripting errors.  I resolved this by enabling the 'CorsFilter' in web.xml for my tomcat installation.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After restarting tomcat, the following function actually retrieved the page instead of throwing a cross-domain scripting error:

```
function listReviews() {
    $.get("http://mydomain:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/", function(data) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

However, the data was empty:

```
{"size":0,"limit":25,"isLastPage":true,"values":[],"start":0}
```

I figured out it needs authentication to retrieve the data I was requesting (logging out of stash resulted in the same empty response), so I created the following:

```
function listReviews() {
    var urlBase = 'http://mydomain:7990/rest/api/1.0/';
    var urlPart = 'projects/';
    var urlFull = urlBase+urlPart;
    var username = 'username';
    var password = 'password';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urlFull,
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        success: function() { $('#content').append("success<br>"); },
        error: function() { $('#content').append("fail<br>"); }
    });
}
```

However, it's now giving me a different error I'm having trouble resolving.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

The username and password are right.  If I look at the Response Headers for the first `listReviews()` function, I see

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mydomain
```

However, with the second `listReviews()` function, the response (403) headers do not include the above, which seems to be the issue.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be with authentication though, per "*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*" in the response. Seems to *still* be a Cors issue.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks, Marcus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I figure it out nearly immediately after writing an extensive StackOverflow question.

Changed the tomcat web.xml filter that enables CORS to the following.  Apparently "Authorization" isn't enabled by default.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```